# Running tests with maven packaging type "pom"

Tags: maven, junit, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm having some issues running my unit tests when my pom is set to packaging type "pom". At first, it was saying no goals needed for this project, so I added the maven-surefire-plugin to my pom.xml to bind the test phase to the maven-surefire-plugin test goal.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now the surefire plugin is getting executed, but it says there are no tests to run.  If I change the packaging type to jar and run mvn test then it picks up my tests files.

When I run mvn test -X it says "testSourceDirectory = C:\dev\dsl\src\test\java", which is the correct location.  Is the test location different for the packaging type "pom" than for "jar"?  I tried adding

```
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
```

to the surefire plugin, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: Pom packaging is for metadata-only projects, no? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm actually in this same scenario - I have a module of system tests only that I'd like to run but not produce a jar out of them.  However I can't get tests to run without actually specifying a packaging type of something besides pom.  How would I do that (this is probably worthy of a separate question).

Comment: @DaveNewton I wanted to do this because it wasn't a java application, I wanted to produce a zip file with database scripts as the artifact.

Comment: @whaley As indicated below, you would need to bind the compiler:testCompile goal to the test-compile phase, and surefire:test to the test phase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As commented by Dave, if you are using `pom` packaging, it only executes the following lifecycle goals.  Refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) related maven documentation.

- package
- install
- deploy

If you need it to run any other goal, you would need to explicitly specify it.  For instance,

```
mvn clean compiler:testCompile surefire:test
```

Comment: Oh thank you!  I knew it wasn't tied to the test phase, but it didn't click in my head that I would need to run compiler:testCompile as well.

Comment: One more question.  I thought I could this to bind compiler:testCompile to the test phase, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>test-compile</phase>
<goals>
<goal>testCompile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

Comment: Never mind, I had two maven-compiler-plugin sections, so it was getting overridden

Comment: I use this as mvn clean package compiler:testCompile surefire:test because i got errors without the package