# TestNG test does not start test if packaging tag in pom.xml is 'pom'<packaging>pom</packaging>

Tags: maven, cucumber, packaging, testng.xml

I am using TestNg runner to run my cucumber test cases.
For this I am using modular design.

Automation_Project
Module 1 -> which have all the stepdefnination and feature files.
Module 2  -> which have all the locators , actioncode and other utility part code.

Main pom.xml have all the configuration mentioned
Module level pom and main pom packaging is 'pom'
When I try to run testng through testng.xml it is not event starting test.

But if I make packaging 'jar' then I am able to run test.

For project requirement I need to keep my packaging 'pom'.
Is there any way I can run my test via testng keeping packaging type pom

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/8845858/679824

Comment: If packging is pom it can not start because it is assumed that kind of package does not contain any source code nor test code... Please make an example on github... Why do you need to keep packaging `pom`? Does not make sense...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.